# UWP MVVM on click bind to function

Tags: c#, mvvm, uwp

This is probably the easiest thing in the world to do but I'm struggling a bit.

I have this in XAML:

```
<Button Name="browseButton" Content="Browse" Grid.Column="1" />
```

I've got everything binding correctly from the view to the viewmodel, like radio buttons and input text boxes etc... but what I want is to bind this button to a function, such that when the user clicks it some operation occurs.

But I'm really having a hard time figuring out how to bind clicking this button to a function in the viewmodel. I've played a bit with ICommand and didn't get very far, and I don't want to do the hack-ish thing of just sticking it in the code behind.

I'm using MVVMLight (Galasoft) if that helps.

Any guidance appreciated.

### Edit

Following the example from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn237302.aspx I have, but where does `canExecuteMyCommand` come into it? And how do I bind it in the XAML?

```
    public RelayCommand BrowseCommand
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public LoadFilesViewModel()
    {
        BrowseCommand = new RelayCommand(executeBrowse, () => _canExecuteMyCommand);
    }

    private void executeBrowse()
    {
        // Do something 
    }
```

### Solution

```
<Button Name="browseButton" Content="Browse" Grid.Column="1" Command="{Binding BrowseCommand}" />
```

And

```
    public RelayCommand BrowseCommand
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public LoadFilesViewModel()
    {
        BrowseCommand = new RelayCommand(executeBrowse, () => true);
    }

    private void executeBrowse()
    {
        // Do something 
    }
```

Comment: Just use RelayCommand from Galasoft toolkit in the viewmodel. In constructor of your viewmodel initialize the RelayCommand with your specific function. Then bind button's command to the property in your viewmodel and that's it. What exactly is not working?

Comment: Do you mind elaborating on this a bit? I think this is what I want but I don't fully understand what you mean. Thanks

Comment: Sure, but what part exactly you don't understand?

Comment: I have updated the first message to show the code I tried. I'm not sure what 1) `_canExecuteMyCommand` is for, and 2) how do I link it to the button in the XAML?

Comment: 1) _canExecute is for enabling, disabling the button. It automatically evaluates the expression and if it false it disables the button. You may not specify it, so it will be always enabled. 2) to bind it in xaml use some simple binding like Command="{Binding BrowseCommand}"

Comment: Thank you for your help, that worked

Comment: Great, just always try to provide more specific details about your problem, you would get help more easily ;) Have a nice day.

Comment: _"I've played a bit with ICommand and didn't get very far"_ -- play some more. I'm glad you were able to figure this out, but for future reference, the above question is far too broad. It's basically a request for a tutorial. A better question would show a good [mcve] and ask for help about some _specific_ issue relating to that code.

Comment: You can use `Click={x:bind view.Click}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the code you provided, the `RelayCommand` constructor comes with 2 parameters.

```
public RelayCommand BrowseCommand
{
    get;
    private set;
}

public LoadFilesViewModel()
{
    BrowseCommand = new RelayCommand(executeBrowse, () => _canExecuteMyCommand);
}

private void executeBrowse()
{
    // Do something 
}
```

Checking the [source code](https://github.com/paulcbetts/mvvmlight/blob/master/GalaSoft.MvvmLight/GalaSoft.MvvmLight%20(NET35)/Command/RelayCommand.cs#L66) (that's the learning a code base and open-source makes this possible) or Visual Studio IntelliSense, you'll see this signature:

```
public RelayCommand(Action execute, Func<bool> canExecute)
```

So the first parameter is an action to be executed, and the second parameter is a check if it can execute. You've correctly identified the `executeBrowse` as a method to "do something". The `_canExecuteMyCommand` parameter is a class variable of the type `bool` that can be either true or false (set somewhere else).

In your own solution (posted in question), you replaced this by true (hardcoded). Note that you can also drop the second parameter in this case:

```
public LoadFilesViewModel()
{
    BrowseCommand = new RelayCommand(executeBrowse); // will always execute
}
```

**Bonus**

Note that instead of using a local variable, you can also use a method to defined whether the method can execute (or write the check logic inline with the delegate syntax).

```
public LoadFilesViewModel()
{
    BrowseCommand = new RelayCommand(ExecuteBrowse, CanExecuteBrowse);
}

private void ExecuteBrowse()
{
    // Do something 
}

private bool CanExecuteBrowse()
{
    // Check if we are allowed to browser
    return true; // or false :)
}
```